# Execute a WHERE clause before another one

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have the following statement

```
SELECT * FROM foo
WHERE LEN(bar) = 4 AND CONVERT(Int,bar) >= 5000
```

The values in `bar` with a length of exactly 4 characters are integers. The other values are not integers and therefore it throws an conversion exception, when trying to convert one of them to an integer.

I thought it's enough to put the `LEN(bar)` before the `CONVERT(Int,bar) >= 5000`. But it's not.

How can I kind of prioritize a specific where clause? In my example I obviously want to select all values with a length of 4, before converting and comparing them.

Comment: What version of sql-server are you using?

Comment: http://rusanu.com/2009/09/13/on-sql-server-boolean-operator-short-circuit/

Comment: SQL Server 2005 (just added the tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

6 answers and 5 of them don't work (for SQL Server)...

```
SELECT *
  FROM foo
 WHERE CASE WHEN LEN(bar) = 4 THEN
       CASE WHEN CONVERT(Int,bar) >= 5000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       END = 1;
```

The WHERE/INNER JOIN conditions can be executed in any order that the query optimizer determines is best. There is no short-circuit boolean evaluation.

Specifically for your question, since you KNOW that the data with 4-characters is a number, then you can do a direct lexicographical (text) comparison (yes it works):

```
SELECT *
  FROM foo
 WHERE LEN(bar) = 4 AND bar > '5000';
```

Comment: +1 for the explanation why some of the other answers don't work.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT bar FROM 
(
SELECT  CASE
       WHEN LEN(bar) = 4 THEN   CAST( bar as int) 
       ELSE  CAST(-1 as int) END bar
FROM Foo
) Foo
WHERE bar>5000
```