# T-SQL view where statement order

Tags: t-sql, sql-view

I have the following problem:
I have an SQL table which contains texts and numbers in one column. I created two views to handle the texts and the numbers.

If I select the views in whole, they work as expected, but if I add a where statement to the select statement, I get the following error:

`Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Thomas' to data type int.`

Can I somehow tell the server to apply for the inner view's where statement before the outer select's one?

Please use the following SQL code for reproducing the error:

```sql
create schema tst
go
create table tst.tbl(strValue varchar(10))
insert tst.tbl(strValue)
    values ('Thomas'), ('1991'), ('Reto'), ('21'), ('Strub')
go
create view tst.tblStr as
    select strValue
    from tst.tbl
    where isnumeric(strValue)=0
go
create view tst.tblInt as
    select cast(strValue as int) intValue
    from tst.tbl
    where isnumeric(strValue)=1

go

select * from tst.tblStr order by strValue --ok
select * from tst.tblInt order by intValue --ok

go

select * from tst.tblInt where intValue<100 --not ok

go

select * from tst.tbl where isnumeric(strValue)=1 and cast(strValue as int) < 100 --ok

go

drop view tst.tblInt
drop view tst.tblStr
drop table tst.tbl
drop schema tst
```

Comment: Your error message (`Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Thomas' to data type int.`) suggests that `Thomas` is in `tst.tblInt`. How come that has happened?

Comment: that's not it... it just applied the where clauses in wrong order...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a "case when" for view tst.tblInt.

```
 create view tst.tblInt as
    select 
            case when isnumeric(strValue)=1 
                then cast(strValue as int)
                else 0 
            end  intValue

    from tst.tbl
    where isnumeric(strValue)=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I belive answer you already posted, just modfied a single line please check

```
CREATE SCHEMA TST
GO
CREATE TABLE TST.TBL(STRVALUE VARCHAR(10))
INSERT TST.TBL(STRVALUE)
VALUES ('THOMAS'), ('1991'), ('RETO'), ('21'),('24'),('212'), ('STRUB')
GO
CREATE VIEW TST.TBLSTR AS
SELECT STRVALUE
FROM TST.TBL
WHERE ISNUMERIC(STRVALUE)=0
GO
CREATE VIEW TST.TBLINT AS
SELECT CAST(STRVALUE AS INT) INTVALUE
FROM TST.TBL
WHERE ISNUMERIC(STRVALUE)=1

GO

SELECT * FROM TST.TBLSTR ORDER BY STRVALUE --OK
SELECT * FROM TST.TBLINT ORDER BY INTVALUE --OK

GO

**SELECT * FROM TST.TBLINT WHERE ISNUMERIC(INTVALUE)<100 --NOW OK ;)**

GO

SELECT * FROM TST.TBL WHERE ISNUMERIC(STRVALUE)=1 AND CAST(STRVALUE AS INT) < 100 --OK

GO

DROP VIEW TST.TBLINT
DROP VIEW TST.TBLSTR
DROP TABLE TST.TBL
DROP SCHEMA TST
```

Comment: This could still be incorrect as where conditions can be executed in any order. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13678718/execute-a-where-clause-before-another-one/13678854#13678854

Comment: Although the wink similey was not meant for something like that..but still SELECT * FROM TST.TBLINT WHERE ISNUMERIC(INTVALUE)=1 AND ISNUMERIC(INTVALUE) <100 will work so its doesn't matter even if the where statment is multiline.

Comment: OK, but `ISNUMERIC(INTVALUE)<100` is always true as `isnumeric` returns either `0` or `1`